# Why the tf.name_scope with same name is different?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the code snippet：

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope('y'):
    a1 = tf.Variable(1,name='a')

with tf.name_scope('y'):
    a2 = tf.Variable(1,name='b')

print(a1.name)
print(a2.name)
```

The output is

```
y/a:0
y_1/b:0
```

Why the the name_scope of variable a2 is y_1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6007) there is an interesting discussion regarding this topic.

What you could do it append a '/' at the end, making it an absolute identifier:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope('y'):
    a1 = tf.Variable(1,name='a')

with tf.name_scope('y/'):
    a2 = tf.Variable(1,name='b')

print(a1.name)
print(a2.name)
```

Which yields:

```
y/a:0
y/b:0
```

The same also applies to [tf.variable_scope()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope).

The bottomline to your question is likely that Tensorflow can't know whether you explicitely want to append something to the scope or whether somewhere else somebody created a different scope and wants to protect you against unintentional re-use. By appending a '/' at the end you turn the name into an absolute identifier.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) `tf.variable_scope` works similarly to `tf.name_scope`, but calling it with `/` at the end will _not_ have that effect there 2) since using `/` with `tf.name_scope` makes the scope absolute, parent scope is _not_ inherited; you can use [`get_name_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_name_scope) to make a complete absolute scope ([see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6007#issuecomment-315030061)) 3) you can reuse a `name_scope` ([see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6007#issuecomment-264837281)).

Comment: @jdehesa  I have tried, `tf.variable_scope` can also have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

The `tf.name_scope` returns a *new* context manager everytime when it's called with a string as the `name` parameter, it doesn't matter if you supply a name that has been seen before, in that case, the name of the scope will simply be made unique by calling `unique_name(name)`.

If you want to re-entry the same name scope, you have to capture it somewhere, and use that scope as the parameter for `name_scope`.

Example taken from `ops.py`:

```
  # Creates a scope called "nested"
  with g.name_scope("nested") as scope:
    nested_c = tf.constant(10.0, name="c")
    assert nested_c.op.name == "nested/c"
    # Creates a nested scope called "inner".
    with g.name_scope("inner"):
      nested_inner_c = tf.constant(20.0, name="c")
      assert nested_inner_c.op.name == "nested/inner/c"
    # Create a nested scope called "inner_1".
    with g.name_scope("inner"):
      nested_inner_1_c = tf.constant(30.0, name="c")
      assert nested_inner_1_c.op.name == "nested/inner_1/c"
      # Treats `scope` as an absolute name scope, and
      # switches to the "nested/" scope.
      with g.name_scope(scope):
        nested_d = tf.constant(40.0, name="d")
        assert nested_d.op.name == "nested/d"
        with g.name_scope(""):
          e = tf.constant(50.0, name="e")
          assert e.op.name == "e"
```

And apparently you can put a slash ('/') at the end of the name to avoid it to be `unique_name`d.

Comment: This is highly inconvenient when you try to reuse name scopes created by others, e.g., GRUCell and tf.while_loop. The only "elegant" workaround I can think of is to implement custom_getter for the underlying get_variable, which is often not exposed publicly.